# C++ Reset array to null

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find the average and it works for the first set of numbers I input but the second set is slightly off, I'm assuming that this is because I haven't reset the array correctly or I'm missing resetting one of the values in it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    int array [15];
    int amount, step, length;
    double total;
    step = -1;
    amount = 0;
    length = 0;
    total = 0;

    cin >> amount;

    for(int count = 0; count!=amount; count++){

        while (array[step] != 0){
            step++;
            cin >> array[step];
        }
        length = step;

        while (step >= 0){
            total = total + array[step];
            array[step] = 0;
            step--;
        }
        total = total / length;
        cout << round(total) << " ";
        step = -1;

    }


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
step = -1;
```

First process of code

```
while (array[step] != 0){
```

produces undefined behavior. First entry of array should be indexed with 0.